# Rhetorical Sentence Pattern

Tags: sentence-patterns

What is the rhetorical sentence pattern of the sentence, "Facts are to the scientist what words are for the poet."? I really think it's **periodic**, but if it's not, can I please have an explanation as to why?

Why I think it's **periodic**:
My understanding is that the noun, **"what words are for the poet"** is how facts occur **to the scientist**. To explain further, given my view of the semantics of the sentence, a rephrased sentence would be: To the scientist, facts are **what words are for the poet**. The definition of a periodic sentence is that the main point is at the end.

My argument is that it is not a balance sentence.

Comment: @Ken It looks like you have two accounts: you can get them merged by following [the advice in the Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

The general term is **analogy**.

The A : B :: C : D format is known as the [Aristotelian format](http://dashingbean.com/?p=64):

> If you took the SAT test sometime before 2005, you are no doubt
>   familiar with Analogy Questions in the Aristotelian format, SKY : BLUE
>   :: GRASS : **_**. (Sky is to Blue as Grass is to what?)  [tresna, DashingBean]

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy):

> In ancient Greek the word αναλογια (analogia) originally meant
>   proportionality, in the mathematical sense, and it was indeed
>   sometimes translated to Latin as proportio. From there analogy was
>   understood as identity of relation between any two ordered pairs,
>   whether of mathematical nature or not. Kant's Critique of Judgment
>   held to this notion. Kant argued that there can be exactly the same
>   relation between two completely different objects. The same notion of
>   analogy was used in the US-based SAT tests, that included "analogy
>   questions" in the form "A is to B as C is to what?" For example, "Hand
>   is to palm as foot is to ____?" These questions were usually given in
>   the Aristotelian format:
>
> HAND : PALM : : FOOT : ____
>
> While most competent English speakers will
>   immediately give the right answer to the analogy question (sole), it
>   is more difficult to identify and describe the exact relation that
>   holds both between hand and palm, and between foot and sole[citation
>   needed][original research?]. This relation is not apparent in some
>   lexical definitions of palm and sole, where the former is defined as
>   the inner surface of the hand, and the latter as the underside of the
>   foot. Analogy and abstraction are different cognitive processes, and
>   analogy is often an easier one.
>
> It's important to note that the above analogy is not comparing all the
>   properties between a hand and a foot, but rather comparing the
>   relationship between a hand and its palm to a foot and its sole.
>   While a hand and a foot have many dissimilarities, the analogy is
>   focusing on their similarity in having an inner surface.

lovanda at [Wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2183371) adds:

> Grammatically  A is to B as C is to D and  A is to B what C is to D
>   are both correct.

There is a subtlety involved here in that the 'to' in 'facts are to the scientist' carries increased semantic weight. Beyond the 'relates to' sense (eg of 50 : 100) is the 'are, in the arsenal ...' sense (ie 'facts are the bread and butter of the scientist').